# IOS crashed after clear cache

Tags: ios, caching

I want to clear image cache but my application crashed when I open it.

Code:

```
dispatch_async(
               dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
               , ^{
                   NSString *cachPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

                   NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsAtPath:cachPath];
                   for (NSString *p in files) {
                       NSError *error;
                       NSString *path = [cachPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:p];
                       if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
                           [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
                       }
                   }
                   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(clearCacheSuccess) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];});
 }
```

**Crash report:**

> > cacheDirectory=/Users/DHR/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/79619360-6D97-432A-AAA0-EF72F2F3F32A/data/Containers/Data/Application/3F491654-3F6E-4AFC-9600-5FD9A3EA75C1/Library/Caches
> >
> > -[__NSCFNumber stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000000c3

I search this path but there is noting.I delete my app and reset content and settings in simulator but it cannot work.

Comment: I don't think the crash is in the code you show.  Please post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: NSString *path = [cachPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/"]; NSString *path1 = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];              if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path1]) {
                           [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path1 error:&error];
                       }                                                                                                         I wrote like this ,something must be wrong at this code ,because my app is  good before I wrote this code.

Comment: And now even though I use command+z to go back to the right code,app still crash...